# Cannot add func to interface

Tags: go, interface

I have this:

```
type Foo interface {
    GetURL() string
}

type ESInfo struct {
    Host string
    Port int
    Foo
}
```

I try to create  a new instance of ESInfo

```
   esinfo := sync.ESInfo{
        Host: "es-dev.cm2.com",
        Port: 9200,
        GetURL: func() string {
          return esinfo.Host + ":" + esinfo.Port
        }
    }
```

but I get this:

> Cannot use 'func() {  }' (type func()) as type Foo

I have no idea what's going on. :(

Comment: Okay, but *why* is it that way? Obviously `Foo` is the wrong type to be useful, but why does it exist? What do you hope to accomplish with it?

Comment: I would do this: `func (s ESInfo) getURL() {return esinfo.Host + ":" + esinfo.Port}`

I don't know why you would use an interface. To me, the interface says there exists a bunch of things that can be 'Foo-ers' which has a method `GetURL`. (if I have that correct). If you don't need that Foo-ness elsewhere, just add a method to the original type. Also, I don't think we embed interfaces... read the spec again about interfaces + embedding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might benefit from some elementary tutorial on Go interfaces.

What's going on is that you're trying to set a function pointer member variable on type ESinfo, and no such member exists. To implement an interface, you have to define a *method* for that type:

```
func (e ESInfo) GetURL() string {
  // Function body here
}
```

After this, ESInfo will be implementing your interface.